# How can I render an image (as a byte array) from PostgresSQL as an data: URI with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, postgresql

```
<a href="#" class="image">
    <!--
    <img class="pic-1" src="assets/images/ADC.jpg">
    <img class="pic-2" src="assets/images/ADC.jpg">
    -->
<?php 
    $byteArray = $row['book_pic'];
    $imgData   = base64_encode($byteArray);
    $img       = "<img src= 'data:image/jpeg;base64, $imgData' alt='Image' class='pic-1'/>";
    echo $img;
?>                                                 
</a>
```

I cannot able to convert the byte array to image, what's the solution for this?

Comment: Please post your **rendered** HTML.

Comment: Also, are you absolutely sure the image data is actually a JPEG and not any other type, like PNG or WebP?